# error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'UserAuth'

Tags: angular

I create a `UserAuth` `interface`:

**user-auth.module.ts**

```
export interface UserAuth {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  created_at?: string;
  updated_at?: string;
}
```

, I declare an `authUser` object of this `interface` in **chat.component.ts**:

```
authUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || '{}').value.authUser;
```

I receive this authUser object in **list.component.ts** :

```
@Input() authUser !: UserAuth;
```

I want to declare an object of this `UserAuth` `interface` **list.component.ts**:

```
changeToGroupChat() {
    const user : UserAuth = null; 
    this.selectedAuthUser.emit(user);
  }
```

but it gives me error:

```
error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'UserAuth'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use union type of typescript:

```
const user : UserAuth | null = null;
```

Comment: Such short answers should be added as comments. Or better, explain the problem in your answer.

Comment: I can’t leave comments yet

Comment: That's incorrect, you get that privilege with 50 reputation, you have over 90.

Comment: Sorry, haven’t coutch when my privilege grown. Updated the answer.

Comment: @EvgenyGurevich thx for u answer but its  gives me error again on the second line : `error TS2345: Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserAuth | undefined'.

29     this.selectedAuthUser.emit(user);`

Comment: Change type of your selectedAuthUser property to @Output() selectedAuthUser: EventEmitter<UserAuth | null> = new EventEmitter();  as well.